# What's the key_names and key_types mean?

Tags: abi

```
"tables": [{
  "table": "account",
  "type": "account",
  "index_type": "i64",
  "key_names" : ["account"],
  "key_types" : ["name"]
}
]
```

In the abi file for the table, it has the key_names and key_types, I know it is relative to the index_type, but, when will the two field be used?

Sometimes I just set a uint32_t field as primary key, and the abi will include next fields, which I am afraid will have some impact on the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The `key_names` is a list of the primary key and all the secondary keys.

The `key_types` is the type of each of the respective keys.

In a simple table (only a primary key), the type is always `uint64` or `name`, and they `key_name` is an element from the struct referenced by the `type` variable.